# Lookupset in Brackets

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

The function:

```
=join(      
    lookupset(
        Fields!ID.Value,
        Fields!ID.Value,
        Fields!Name.Value, "DATASET"
        ),
    Environment.NewLine
    )
```

This works fine. Now I want to add brackets **before** and **after** the value, so I tried this:

```
=join(      
    lookupset(
        Fields!ID.Value,
        Fields!ID.Value,
        & " (" & Fields!Name.Value & ")", "DATASET"
        ),
    Environment.NewLine
    )
```

The after-part **& ")"** works fine, but the before-part **& " (" &** is causing an error ([BC30201] Expression expected.) Is there a way to solve the problem inside the lookupset function?

Comment: try removing the 1st `&` as the return expression is wrong as you have it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value starts with a concatenation character `&` so is an invalid expression.

Try using:

```
=join(      
    lookupset(
        Fields!ID.Value,
        Fields!ID.Value,
        " (" & Fields!Name.Value & ")", "DATASET"
        ),
    Environment.NewLine
    )
```